# How do I match a UITabBarSystemItem's localized string?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, nslocalizedstring

I have an application with a `UITabBarController` which is using a `UITabBarSystemItem`(Favorites) for one of the tabs. How do I set the title of respective view controller to be the same localized title of the `UITabBarSystemItem`? `UITabBarItem` when initialized with `initWithTabBarSystemItem` has `nil` for its `title`.